Prompt user with "Save as" option when exporting Selection of cells as PDF
I want to prompt the user with the SaveAs dialog when exporting a specific Selection of cells as a PDF. I found the method .SaveAs but I struggle to understand how to use it for a specific range of cells.
Private Sub Selection_promptSaveAs_PDF()

  
Dim file_name As Variant
file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Adobe PDF File_ (*.pdf), *.pdf")

If file_name <> False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
MsgBox "File Saved!"
End If
End Sub


In which case it would imply the creation of an additional workbook beside the one I'm using and the pdf created, right?

You can use Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat - record a macro while saving using the option to publish only the selection.

The Selection object has a method for that:
Private Sub Selection_promptSaveAs_PDF()
    Dim file_name As Variant

    file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Adobe PDF File_ (*.pdf), *.pdf")

    If file_name <> False Then
        Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=file_name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        MsgBox "File Saved!"
    End If
End Sub




In the end I used Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat (only with FileName) with an IF that checks if the file name in that path already exists and if so it prompts the user to choose if proceed with the overwriting or exit the Sub. But what I would need better is the user to be prompted with Save As option, so that he/she can choose path and name.

If you want the user to choose the filename then why not use GetSaveAsFilename as in your original code?

Because there was a comment (to which I answered - answer still there) to my original post that said the solution to Save As a specific selection of cells (with getSaveAsFilename) implies the saving/creation of an additional workbook, which is something I would avoid and I don't think it's very user friendly. But I might have misunderstood that.

You can still use GetSaveAsFilename - see edit above.

Thanks! It worked. Short experience with VBA, didn't consider I could mix the two things.
